# How reliable is a refurbished Xbox Kinect

Tags: kinect

Gamestop has a great deal on a refurbished xbox kinect:http://www.gamestop.com/xbox-360/consoles/xbox-360-kinect-sensor-with-ac-adapter-gamestop-refurbished/89295
I am looking to buy one for my friend and was wondering if this is reliable. Does anyone have any recommendations, or bad/good experiences with this product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been refurbished by GameStop, not by xbox itself. That would usually be a red-flag, but gamestop is a reliable brand (IMO) so you should not be experiencing any problems with this product. I think it's worth buying it, but getting a warranty is a good idea to be safe.

Comment: Does gamestop have a feature for this? or would I just ask their customer service for one?

Comment: @LBMF_1 You can go ask gamestop directly for a warranty (in store) , they offer warranties for most products and you can buy it for a fair price.